# How to print html5 canvases in which have inline style applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am creating multiple canvas objects through javascript. I have applied some inline style for like background color, background image, transforms like rotate, scale, object top, left etc etc.

Example:

```
function draw(image,flag) {
    image = image.get(0);
    can_cnt = $("#canvases").children('canvas').length;
    $("#canvases").append('<canvas id="case_canvas'+can_cnt+'" data-type="image" width="301" height="501" align="center" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border:0px solid transparent; z-index:-1; "></canvas>');
    var ctx = document.getElementById('case_canvas'+can_cnt).getContext('2d');
    if(flag) {
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.height,image.width);
    } else {
        ctx.drawImage(image,startX,startY,200,200);
    }
}
```

By this method I am adding multiple canvases and applying styles on it as per requirements.

Now, I want that all canvas objects in one image. I have tried multiple ways like

```
$("#temp_canvas_div").html('<canvas id="temp_canvas" width="301" height="501" align="center" >');
        can1 = document.getElementById('temp_canvas');
        ctx1 = can1.getContext("2d");
        $("#canvases canvas").each(function() {

            var coll = document.getElementById($(this).attr('ID'));

            var el = document.getElementById($(this).attr('ID'));
            var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);

            var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
            st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
            st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
            st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
            st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
            "FAIL";

            // rotation matrix - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            if(tr != 'none') {
                var values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
                var a = values[0];
                var b = values[1];
                var c = values[2];
                var d = values[3];
            }

            var scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b) ?  Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b) : 1;

            var h = (500 * scale)
            var w = (300 * scale)

            var x = parseInt((300 - w) / 2);
            var y = parseInt((500 - h) / 2);

            var sx = 0;
            var sy = 0;
            if(parseInt($("#"+$(this).attr('ID')).css('left')) != 0) {
                sx = x + parseInt($("#"+$(this).attr('ID')).css('left'));
            }

            if(parseInt($("#"+$(this).attr('ID')).css('top')) != 0) {
                sy = y + parseInt($("#"+$(this).attr('ID')).css('top'));
            }

            sx = sx != x ? sx : x;
            sy = sy != y ? sy : y;

            ctx1.drawImage(coll, sx, sy, 300,500, x,y,w,h);
        });
        window.open(temp_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

But I am not able to getting exact image like I'm showing on my screen.

Is there any way to print all canvases to one image or canvas with it's current style applied on.

Thanks,